# Проблема с выпадающим меню HTML

Tags: html, css

```
    //HTML
     <div class="Login"><a href="" class="LoginA">Вход</a> / <a 
     href="">Регистрация</a>
         <div class="DropdownMenu">
            <input type="text" placeholer="Email"/>
            <input type="text" placeholer="Password"/>
            <input type="button" value="Войти"/>
            <p>Забыли пароль?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
   //CSS
  .Login {
  float: right;
  padding-left:30px;
  padding-top:30px;
  }
 .DropdownMenu {
 width: 245.19px;
 background-color: gray;
 display: none;
 height: 140px;
 opacity: 0.8;
 text-align:center;
 position:absolute;
 font-size:20px;  
 }
.LoginA:hover .DropdownMenu{
 display: block;
 }
```

Не работает `.LoginA:hover .DropdownMenu`. 
Хочу, чтобы при простом наведении курсора на надпись "Вход" отображалось меню DropdownMenu. 
Но оно не работает...
Хотя если написать просто `.Login:hover .DrodownMenu`, то оно работат 
(но теперь это срабатывает только в том случае, если навести курсор на саму форму Login. 
Как исправить и что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.Login {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.Login>a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.DropdownMenu {
  width: 245.19px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: none;
  height: 140px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.LoginA:hover ~ .DropdownMenu, .DropdownMenu:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="Login"><a class="LoginA">Вход
  </a> / <a>Регистрация</a>
  <div class="DropdownMenu">
    <input type="text" placeholer="Email" />
    <input type="text" placeholer="Password" />
    <input type="button" value="Войти" />
    <p>Забыли пароль?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а разве теперь не стало все DropdownMenu одной большой ссылкой? Можно не заключать это меню в тег <a> и оставить все, как было?

Comment: @BossOfThisGym Можно не заключать.